# Rail 5 assets pre compiled for production but doesn't load gives 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This is the browser console.
[image: loading fails]

application.css

[image]

assets.rb

[image]

Everything runs smoothly on localhost. On production server nothing loads i.e. images, css and js. I am using nginx with puma on aws ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

NGINX config file

[image: NGINX]

Files are copied into public/assets

[image: file public/assets]

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile`? Ran it in production environment locally?

Comment: Yes i did.  I ran it on locally and pushed it.

Comment: RAILS_ENV=production assets:precompile but nothing happens.

Comment: @Tanuj "I wan it locally and pushed it". Are you 100% sure you are including the `public/assets` folder on your source control?

Comment: Also, could you show your nginx config file? I'm pretty sure the error is in there (if you're generating & including the assets folder correctly)

Comment: Sure in a minute.

Comment: @OscarMederos Added the nginx config file to the question. Yes I ran the command locally then I committed on git and pushed it on the server.

Comment: and if you look on the server you see them in the correct place?

Comment: @Doon added my public/assets on the production server image to the question.

Comment: you realize that your root points to /home/deploy/initiatingyou/public and your assets are in  /home/deploy/initiatingyou/current/public ?  could that be part of the problem

Comment: @Doon yes doon kudos, Oscar pointed at that problem too. Thanks you both of you. Thanks a ton :)